# C++ registry class which manages game object, components and systems in an ECS

Tags: c++, c++20, entity-component-system

So this is my header file (`registry.hpp`):

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

#include "steering.hpp"  // This just provides a Vec2d class (has x and y members) and a KinematicObject class (has position and velocity Vec2d and rotation members)

// Add a forward declaration for the registry class
class Registry;

struct ComponentBase {
  ComponentBase() = default;

  virtual ~ComponentBase() = default;

  ComponentBase(const ComponentBase &component) = default;
};

struct SystemBase {
  SystemBase() = default;

  virtual ~SystemBase() = default;

  virtual void update(Registry &registry, float delta_time) {};
};

class RegistryError : public std::runtime_error {
 public:
  template<typename T>
  RegistryError(const std::string &not_registered_type,
                const T &value,
                const std::string &error = "is not registered with the registry") : std::runtime_error(
      "The " + not_registered_type + " `" + to_string(value) + "` " + error + ".") {};

 private:
  template<typename T>
  static std::string to_string(const T &value) {
    return std::to_string(value);
  }

  static std::string to_string(const std::string &value) {
    return value;
  }

  static std::string to_string(const char *value) {
    return value;
  }
};

class Registry {
 public:
  Registry() = default;

  int create_game_object(bool kinematic, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ComponentBase>> &components);

  void delete_game_object(int game_object_id);

  template<typename T>
  std::unique_ptr<T> get_component(int game_object_id) {
    // Check if the game object is registered or not
    if (game_objects_.find(game_object_id) == game_objects_.end()) {
      throw RegistryError{"game object", game_object_id};
    }

    // Check if the component is registered or not
    if (game_objects_[game_object_id].find(typeid(T)) == game_objects_[game_object_id].end()) {
      throw RegistryError{"component", typeid(T).name()};
    }

    // Return the specified component casting it to T
    return std::move(std::unique_ptr<T>(dynamic_cast<T *>(game_objects_[game_object_id][typeid(T)].release())));
  }

  template<typename ... T>
  std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<T> ...>>> get_components() {
    // Create a vector of tuples to store the components
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<T> ...>>> components;

    // Iterate over all game objects
    for (auto &[game_object_id, game_object_components] : game_objects_) {
      // Check if the game object has all the components using a fold expression
      bool has_components = true;
      ((has_components &= game_object_components.find(typeid(T)) != game_object_components.end()), ...);

      // If the game object has all the components, cast them to T and add them
      // to the vector
      if (has_components) {
        components.emplace_back(game_object_id, std::make_tuple(std::move(std::unique_ptr<T>(dynamic_cast<T *>(game_object_components[typeid(T)].release()))) ...));
      }
    }

    // Return the components making sure to
    return components;
  }

  void add_system(std::unique_ptr<SystemBase> system);

  template<typename T>
  std::unique_ptr<T> get_system(std::type_index system) {
    // Check if the system is registered or not
    if (systems_.find(system) == systems_.end()) {
      throw RegistryError{"system", system.name()};
    }

    // Return the system casting it to T
    return std::move(std::unique_ptr<T>(dynamic_cast<T *>(systems_[system].release())));
  }

  void update(float delta_time) {
    for (auto &[_, system] : systems_) {
      system->update(*this, delta_time);
    }
  }

  std::unique_ptr<KinematicObject> get_kinematic_object(int game_object_id);

  void add_wall(std::unique_ptr<Vec2d> wall) {
    walls_.emplace(std::move(wall));
  }

  const std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<Vec2d>> &get_walls() const {
    return walls_;
  }

 private:
  int next_game_object_id_ = 0;
  std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unordered_set<int>> components_;
  std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<ComponentBase>>> game_objects_;
  std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<SystemBase>> systems_;
  std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<KinematicObject>> kinematic_objects_;
  std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<Vec2d>> walls_;
};
```

And the source file (`registry.cpp`):

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "game_objects/registry.hpp"

int Registry::create_game_object(bool kinematic, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ComponentBase>> &components) {
  // Add the game object to the system
  game_objects_[next_game_object_id_] = std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<ComponentBase>>{};
  if (kinematic) {
    kinematic_objects_[next_game_object_id_] = std::make_unique<KinematicObject>(Vec2d{0, 0}, Vec2d{0, 0});
  }

  // Add the game object to the components
  for (auto &component : components) {
    const std::type_info &component_type = typeid(component.get());
    components_[component_type].insert(next_game_object_id_);
    game_objects_[next_game_object_id_][component_type] = std::move(component);
  }

  // Increment the game object ID and return the current game object ID
  next_game_object_id_++;
  return next_game_object_id_ - 1;
}

void Registry::delete_game_object(int game_object_id) {
  // Check if the game object is registered or not
  if (game_objects_.find(game_object_id) == game_objects_.end()) {
    throw RegistryError{"game object", game_object_id};
  }

  // Delete the game object from the system
  game_objects_.erase(game_object_id);
  for (auto [component_type, ids] : components_) {
    ids.erase(game_object_id);
  }
  if (kinematic_objects_.find(game_object_id) != kinematic_objects_.end()) {
    kinematic_objects_.erase(game_object_id);
  }
}

void Registry::add_system(std::unique_ptr<SystemBase> system) {
  // Check if the system is already registered or not
  const std::type_info &system_type = typeid(system.get());
  if (systems_.find(system_type) != systems_.end()) {
    throw RegistryError{"system", system_type.name()};
  }

  // Add the system to the registry
  systems_[system_type] = std::move(system);
}

std::unique_ptr<KinematicObject> Registry::get_kinematic_object(int game_object_id) {
  // Check if the game object is registered or not
  if (kinematic_objects_.find(game_object_id) == kinematic_objects_.end()) {
    throw RegistryError{"game object", game_object_id};
  }

  // Return the kinematic object
  return std::move(kinematic_objects_[game_object_id]);
}
```

I have a few problems which I think can be improved:

- I'm not sure if the copy constructors are needed.
- I may not need to throw a `RegistryError` if something doesn't exist, maybe just return a nullptr?
- The overall design of the registry just seems really hard to work with and not well structured (I'm porting this from my Python version so its a bit different).
- When passing in a subclass of `ComponentBase` (or similarly with `SystemBase`), the object is always stored with a type of `std::unique_ptr<ComponentBase>` which makes it really hard if I want to get a component given a polymorphic type (especially if I want the return type to be the subclass).

How best could I redesign this class to be easier to use and better structured?